# Linking Mulit User Profile Together

Tags: python, django

So i have this Accounts where I have two types of users example: intern, and HR Supervisor. So my models is

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   is_intern = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class InternProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
        related_name='intern_profile')
   bio = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
   SuperVisor= models.ForeignKey(HRProfile, null=True, 
                related_name='employee')

class HRProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='hr_profile')
   company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
   website = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

Now lets suppose i have two HR managers name Alice and Bob. Both Alice and Bob have three interns underneath them working, lets say Sam, David, Katty works under Alice and Drake, Taylor and Nik works under Bob.

Now I want to Bob to see only his intern and Alice can only see her intern not other way round, so guys i m new and learning django any advice related to this , cause i cant able to find the way around this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have everything in one model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='interns')

    def is_supervisor(self):
        if not self.supervisor:
            return True
        return False

    def is_intern(self):
        if not self.supervisor:
            return False
        return True
```

In your view or any function, you can just check if the user is a supervisor and then query his interns.

```
if obj.is_supervisor():
    interns = obj.interns.all()
```

or

```
if obj.is_intern():
    supervisor = obj.supervisor
```